# Committing all files from Android Studio to GitHub

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio

I'm new to the GitHub, and trying to push my project to the GitHub from VCS of Android Studio. When I do this it commits and pushes only .java files and no other files like resources etc.

How can I push the rest of the files?
Thanks.

Comment: you think that's bad?  when i told it to do the initial commit I thought it was committing everything, nearly 50 files it said where ready, but it only committed 1 obscure XML file, and I didn't realize this until I went to make a second commit and it told me I had changes ready in all my files!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Check .gitignore file. http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore
2. Right-click on directory of your project (in Android Studio) -> Git -> Add
   [image]

Comment: Git does not appear in the menu when you right click.

Comment: @StephenKuehl check if you have created Git repository